# Set same width for all columns in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

Using Perl, I am writing a data into XLS sheet from [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel).

I want to set the width of every column to 30.
To set the column of excel sheet from A to H, the code is:

```
$worksheet->set_column('A:H', 30);
```

But not just A to H, I want to set the every column in excel sheet to 30.
How to do that in above format in one line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the cells, keep track of the last column that you write to.
Then at the end do:
$worksheet->set_column(0, $lastColumn, 30);